# Unknown CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am trying the Jenkins for CICD to Pivotal Web Services where CI was successful but the CD is the reverse because of this issue.

Already tried to push using eclipse and it was successful, I just don't what went wrong when via Jenkins. Below is the image of my encountered issue:

[image]

Here is the relevant error message:

```
ERROR: Unknown CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request
ERROR: Cloud Foundry error code: -1
ERROR: The host is taken: sample-test
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone else already has an app bound to `sample-test.run.pivotal.io`, which isn't surprising as it is a massively multi-tenant system. If another user is using that hostname for their app, you'll have to choose something else.

You can use the `--random-route` flag on `cf push` to have Cloud Foundry pick to words at random to add to your chosen hostname, to reduce the likelihood of a name clash.

Answer (score 0):

there have 2 main things which can provoke a Bad request error,
- the domain is already taken (like your own)
- the route contains illegal char like '_' for exemple I had to rename my route application 'webapp_war' to 'wabapp-war2222', but by default some cloundFoundry client like pivotal call your app with route '_war' (so be carefull to rename it)